# How to install html editor manually from browser and import it to eclipse

Tags: java, html, eclipse, web

Web tools is not available in my eclipse so tried to install new software from help menu but it's getting "unable to read repository at [https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-06/content.xml"](https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-06/content.xml%22) error. I tried all the ways to resolve this but still it was not resolved. I tried from eclipse marketplace too but there also getting error. So kindly help me to import the html editor manually to eclipse.

Comment: What are "all the ways"? Which Marketplace offering where you trying, and did it give you the *same* error? Have you tried using https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest ?

Comment: I tried by changing the network configuration and also tried  by start eclipse with this argument
-vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

for market place below error getting: 

MarketplaceDiscoveryStrategy failed with an error
Cannot complete request to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/api/p?
Have you tried using download.eclipse.org/releases/latest ?-------Yes I tried with this.

Comment: Are you sure your Eclipse is up to date and that you are not behind a proxy? It works for me and eclipse.org had no outages in the last days: https://www.eclipsestatus.io/

Comment: Yes it is in up to date.

Comment: Is there any possibility to import the html editor to eclipse by installing externally..